# image rotate plugin(in ckeditor) converts my uploaded images to data:uri

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, image-rotation, image-upload

I use symfony with ckeditor for my forms. I have setup the 'image upload' plugin, and it works fine, uploading images in the disk.

Later I installed the 'rotate image' plugin.

When I upload my images they are in the server:

when I first rotate, they become inline:

The problem is that the data:uri is stored now in my database, and takes much longer to update than simply storing a disk uri.

After I rotate, is it possible to keep my images as were, not convert them to data:image?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a problem of CKEditor itself, but just the way that the "rotate image" plugin works.
You should report the problem to its author